# Determine default protocol version used by SSL package?

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, pyopenssl

In python, how can I determine which SSL or TLS protocol is used by SSL package, or requests, by default.

As in, say TLSv1 vs SSLv3.

Answer (score 0):

The [SSL socket creation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#socket-creation) section of the Python docs has the information on the SSL package:

> The parameter `ssl_version` specifies which version of the SSL
>   protocol to use. Typically, the server chooses a particular protocol
>   version, and the client must adapt to the server’s choice. Most of the
>   versions are not interoperable with the other versions. If not
>   specified, the default is
>   [PROTOCOL_SSLv23](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
>   it provides the most compatibility with other versions.
>
> Here’s a table showing which versions in a client (down the side) can
>   connect to which versions in a server (along the top):
>
> ```
> | client / server | SSLv2 | SSLv3 | SSLv23 | TLSv1 | TLSv1.1 | TLSv1.2 |
> |-----------------|-------|-------|--------|-------|---------|---------|
> | SSLv2           | yes   | no    | yes    | no    | no      | no      |
> | SSLv3           | no    | yes   | yes    | no    | no      | no      |
> | SSLv23          | no    | yes   | yes    | yes   | yes     | yes     |
> | TLSv1           | no    | no    | yes    | yes   | no      | no      |
> | TLSv1.1         | no    | no    | yes    | no    | yes     | no      |
> | TLSv1.2         | no    | no    | yes    | no    | no      | yes     |
> ```
>
> > **Note:**
> >
> > Which connections succeed will vary depending on the version of
> >     OpenSSL. For example, before OpenSSL 1.0.0, an SSLv23 client would
> >     always attempt SSLv2 connections.

Comment: Please use quote blocks when quoting literally blocks of texts from external resources. Otherwise it looks like the content was your original writing/adaptation over the contents provided in the link while that's not true and you just copy&pasted the content that's there.